# How to print from web browser without print dialog?

Tags: php, javascript, printing, lamp

I'm building a LAMP point of sale (PoS) system. At the end of each transaction, I want to print a receipt. However, I do not want to be prompted by the print dialog. Is there a way to disable the print dialog? I will have direct access to every computer that uses the PoS, so I can make any changes to the OS, browser, etc. I'm looking for a solution that works cross platform, cross browser.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make each PoS station a print server. Have the web server print to the same station that the request came from.

Comment: Interesting approach...  Assuming, of course, that every PoS has a dedicated printer.

Comment: I'm not sure if each PoS will have its own dedicated printer or share a printer among PoS that are clustered together. Can you please elaborate a bit about your solution, though?

Comment: Mapping printer to station should be easy enough, if required. Add the PoS print servers to the web server's print spooler, then use `lp` or whatnot to direct the document to the appropriate print server.

Comment: Sorry, still a bit lost. Any instructions I can follow online somewhere?

Comment: You mean like, how to configure CUPS, or what?

Comment: No clue what CUPS is, either. What do I need to do to make the PoS station a print server? And how do I make the web server print to "the same station that the request came from?"